# Is there QGIS Portal similar to Portal for ArcGIS?

Tags: qgis, qgis-server

I'm a beginner.

ArcGIS Pro provides a wide range of maps/data via its "All Portal". They have a few excellent maps I would like to use.

Is there an equivalent service from within QGIS or do I need to subscribe to ArcGIS to utilise these maps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NextGIS Web is server GIS, which features is very close to ESRI All Portal (if you mean this [software](http://enterprise.arcgis.com/en/portal/latest/administer/windows/what-is-portal-for-arcgis-.htm)). You can [install it on your server](http://docs.nextgis.com/docs_ngweb/source/sysadmin.html) or use it in a [cloud](http://nextgis.com/).

NextGIS Web features:

- vector layers with different styles (unlimited styles for one layer)
- raster layers
- external database layers (i.e. PostGIS)
- external WMS layers
- basemaps from [QuickMapServices](https://qms.nextgis.com/)
- ability to create own WMS, WFS services for desktop GIS
- unlimited web maps

Also you can [manage user rights](http://docs.nextgis.com/docs_ngweb/source/admin_tasks.html#setting-permissions) for all you data (layers, maps, services, etc.).

There is integration with QGIS using [NextGIS Connect](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/nextgis_connect/). You can publish you QGIS map via [one click](http://docs.nextgis.com/docs_ngcom/source/ngqgis_connect.html#creating-and-uploading-a-whole-qgis-project-to-web-gis).

Additionally there is the [mobile client](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nextgis.mobile) for offline work, also integrated with NextGIS Web.

See [documentation](http://docs.nextgis.com/index.html).

**Disclosure**: I am a developer from NextGIS.